# Delete a specific Frame which is made in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, delete-operator

I have check boxes , generated by a for loop.

```
def MakeMaterialsButtons(self):
        self.ChoosingVariable = ctk.IntVar(value=0)
        CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT idmaterials FROM materials WHERE mat_category = %s '
        CallDB.execute(query, (StickersName,))
        Stickers_Categories_ID3 = CallDB.fetchall()
        i = 1
        j = 1
        mat_distance = 10
        x_mat_distance = 10
        for stickers_item in Stickers_Categories_ID3:
            get_mat_ID_str = str(stickers_item)
            get_mat_ID = get_mat_ID_str[1:-2]
            int(get_mat_ID)
            if mat_distance >= 150:
                x_mat_distance = x_mat_distance + 200
                mat_distance = 10
            self.MakeOrderButtonsForStickers(get_mat_ID, mat_distance, x_mat_distance)
            j = j + 1
            mat_distance = mat_distance + 60



def MakeOrderButtonsForStickers(self, get_mat_ID, mat_distance, x_mat_distance):

    get_mat_name = get_NameOfMaterial(get_mat_ID)
    ItembyCategoryCheckBox = ctk.CTkCheckBox(self.StickersFrame, text=get_mat_name,
                                             command=lambda: self.Add_To_Order_Materials(get_mat_ID, get_mat_name),
                                             fg_color="#a881af", variable=self.ChoosingVariable,
                                             onvalue="1", offvalue="0", width=150, height=40,
                                             text_color='black', font=("arial bold", 20),
                                             border_width=4,
                                             border_color='black')
    ItembyCategoryCheckBox.place(x=x_mat_distance, y=mat_distance)
```

And this is the function when i am checking it.

```
def Add_To_Order_Materials(self, Mat_ID, mat_name):
    print(self.ChoosingVariable.get())
    Mat_Price = get_PriceOfMaterial(Mat_ID)
    if self.ChoosingVariable.get() == 1:
        if mat_name != self.Name_Order_Counter:
            self.Item_Order_Counter = 1
            self.Item_Order_Distance = self.Item_Order_Distance + 30
            self.Name_Order_Counter = mat_name
            self.Material_Order_Text = ctk.CTkLabel(self.ordertotalframe, text=mat_name, font=("arial bold", 20),
                                                text_color='black')
            self.Material_Order_Text.place(x=55, y=self.Item_Order_Distance)
            self.Material_quantity_text = ctk.CTkLabel(self.ordertotalframe, text=(str(self.Item_Order_Counter) + "x"),
                                                   font=("arial bold", 20), text_color='black')
            self.Material_quantity_text.place(x=210, y=self.Item_Order_Distance)
            self.Material_price_text = ctk.CTkLabel(self.ordertotalframe, text=(str(Mat_Price) + " €"),
                                                font=("arial bold", 20), text_color='black')
            self.Material_price_text.place(x=300, y=self.Item_Order_Distance)
            self.Item_Order_Counter = self.Item_Order_Counter + 1
            self.Order_Total_price = self.Order_Total_price + Mat_Price
            self.Order_Total_price_Label.configure(text=(str(self.Order_Total_price) + " €"))
            self.Material_Order_Text.place()

        else:
            self.Material_quantity_text.configure(text=(str(self.Item_Order_Counter) + "x"))
            self.Material_Order_Text.configure(text=mat_name)
            self.Item_Order_Counter = self.Item_Order_Counter + 1
            self.Order_Total_price = self.Order_Total_price + Mat_Price
            self.Order_Total_price_Label.configure(text=(str(self.Order_Total_price) + " €"))
    else:
        self.Name_Order_Counter = ""
        self.Material_Order_Text.place_forget()
        self.Material_quantity_text.place_forget()
        self.Material_price_text.place_forget()
        self.Item_Order_Distance = self.Item_Order_Distance - 30
        self.Order_Total_price = self.Order_Total_price - Mat_Price
        self.Order_Total_price_Label.configure(text=(str(round(self.Order_Total_price, 2)) + " €"))
```

So its basicly adds the material price on a frame which is getting the total of an order.
If i check two of the options i want , and then i want to remove the first option i checked, it just doing these lines

```
            self.Item_Order_Distance = self.Item_Order_Distance - 30
            self.Order_Total_price = self.Order_Total_price - Mat_Price
            self.Order_Total_price_Label.configure(text=(str(round(self.Order_Total_price, 2)) + "
```

It doesnt remove the previous choice , but only the last i checked.
Any ideas ? Do i have to add a table and do something with that , on every each button which is made? How can i do that

Comment: Where is the `for` loop?

Comment: @barmar I did add the for loop

Comment: Why are you clearing `self.Name_Order_Counter` when you uncheck an option?

Comment: I'm not sure what most of this code is doing. But it seems like when you click on a checkbox, all you have to do is add or subtract `Mat_price` from the total price depending on whether it's checked or unchecked.

Comment: well self.name_order_counter does nothing , i just saw that haha

Comment: @barmar yeah that's right for the rest , adds or substracts the total price of the order , but if i will check two of the materials , and then let's say i want to unckeck the first choice , its not getting deleted. i can only delete the latest choice i checked

Comment: What do you mean it's not getting deleted? Deleted from where?

Comment: the fuction Add_to Order_Materials is also generating labeles based on the checkbox is checked or not. For ex. if i ll check a material which is called "Small Bag" and then i check another material which is called "Candle Sticker", it generates labels with tha name of the material and the price of that. So i want to uncheck the "Candle Sticker"(my 2nd choice) , it will destroy() the generated labels , but if i want to uncheck the "Small Bag" it will just abstract the price from the total price , but the labels are gonna stay there and not being destroyed. Was tha clear ? :P @barmar

Comment: Add a property with the list of all the labels. Then when you uncheck a button, you can remove the label from the list.

Comment: @barmar would you mind , to show me an example , cause i am learning while doing this program , and i cannot really understand from the videos or tutorials

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Should each checkbox has its own tkinter variable instead of using same `self.ChoosingVariable`?

Answer (score 0):

Return the sticker in your `MakeOrderButtonsForStickers` function like so:

```py
def MakeOrderButtonsForStickers(self, get_mat_ID, mat_distance, x_mat_distance):

    get_mat_name = get_NameOfMaterial(get_mat_ID)
    ItembyCategoryCheckBox = ctk.CTkCheckBox(self.StickersFrame, text=get_mat_name,
                                             command=lambda: self.Add_To_Order_Materials(get_mat_ID, get_mat_name),
                                             fg_color="#a881af", variable=self.ChoosingVariable,
                                             onvalue="1", offvalue="0", width=150, height=40,
                                             text_color='black', font=("arial bold", 20),
                                             border_width=4,
                                             border_color='black')
    ItembyCategoryCheckBox.place(x=x_mat_distance, y=mat_distance)
    return ItembyCategoryCheckBox
```

Then you can create a member variable of your class, like `sticker_checkboxes`, and assign by index in the for-loop using `enumerate`.

```py
        ...
        for idx, stickers_item in enumerate(Stickers_Categories_ID3):
            get_mat_ID_str = str(stickers_item)
            get_mat_ID = get_mat_ID_str[1:-2]
            int(get_mat_ID)
            if mat_distance >= 150:
                x_mat_distance = x_mat_distance + 200
                mat_distance = 10
            
            self.sticker_checkboxes[idx] = self.MakeOrderButtonsForStickers(get_mat_ID, mat_distance, x_mat_distance)
            j = j + 1
            mat_distance = mat_distance + 60
```

Now you have a list of your checkboxes, in the order you created them. You could also make `sticker_checkboxes` as a dict, and index on `get_mat_ID`, up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used same set of instance variables (`self.Material_Order_Text`, `self.Material_quantity_text` and `self.Material_price_text`) for all the items *checked*, so they will refer to the last item checked.

I would suggest to use a dictionary to store those created labels using the *Mat_ID* as the key, then you can easily access them using the *Mat_ID*.

Below is the modified `Add_To_Order_Materials()`:

```py
def Add_To_Order_Materials(self, Mat_ID, mat_name):
    print(self.ChoosingVariable.get())
    Mat_Price = get_PriceOfMaterial(Mat_ID)
    if self.ChoosingVariable.get() == 1:
        if mat_name != self.Name_Order_Counter:
            self.Item_Order_Counter = 1
            self.Item_Order_Distance = self.Item_Order_Distance + 30
            self.Name_Order_Counter = mat_name
            self.Material_Order_Text = ctk.CTkLabel(self.ordertotalframe, text=mat_name, font=("arial bold", 20),
                                                text_color='black')
            self.Material_Order_Text.place(x=55, y=self.Item_Order_Distance)
            self.Material_quantity_text = ctk.CTkLabel(self.ordertotalframe, text=(str(self.Item_Order_Counter) + "x"),
                                                   font=("arial bold", 20), text_color='black')
            self.Material_quantity_text.place(x=210, y=self.Item_Order_Distance)
            self.Material_price_text = ctk.CTkLabel(self.ordertotalframe, text=(str(Mat_Price) + " €"),
                                                font=("arial bold", 20), text_color='black')
            self.Material_price_text.place(x=300, y=self.Item_Order_Distance)
            self.Item_Order_Counter = self.Item_Order_Counter + 1
            self.Order_Total_price = self.Order_Total_price + Mat_Price
            self.Order_Total_price_Label.configure(text=(str(self.Order_Total_price) + " €"))
            self.Material_Order_Text.place()

            # ************************************************************ 
            # use a dictionary self.order_item_labels to store the labels
            # note that self.order_item_labels should be initialized
            #   elsewhere, for example inside __init__()
            self.order_item_labels[Mat_ID] = (self.Material_Order_Text, self.Material_quantity_text, self.Material_price_text)

        else:
            self.Material_quantity_text.configure(text=(str(self.Item_Order_Counter) + "x"))
            self.Material_Order_Text.configure(text=mat_name)
            self.Item_Order_Counter = self.Item_Order_Counter + 1
            self.Order_Total_price = self.Order_Total_price + Mat_Price
            self.Order_Total_price_Label.configure(text=(str(self.Order_Total_price) + " €"))
    else:
        self.Name_Order_Counter = ""
        # clear removed order item
        for lbl in self.order_item_labels[Mat_ID]:
            lbl.place_forget()
        # remove the item from order list
        self.order_item_labels.pop(Mat_ID, None)
        # populate order list
        for i, labels in enumerate(self.order_item_labels.values(), 1):
            y = i * 30
            labels[0].place(x=55, y=y)
            labels[1].place(x=210, y=y)
            labels[2].place(x=300, y=y)

        self.Item_Order_Distance = self.Item_Order_Distance - 30
        self.Order_Total_price = self.Order_Total_price - Mat_Price
        self.Order_Total_price_Label.configure(text=(str(round(self.Order_Total_price, 2)) + " €"))
```

Comment: Well as you can see i am very new to this. I know how dictionary works but i am not really used to how to use it. I almost copied and pasted what you saw me , the only difference is the name of the dictionary and that i initialized it at the beggining of the class. I got an error which is "..., line 718, in Add_To_Order_Materials
    for lbl in self.order_material_labels[str(Mat_ID)]:
  File
"...", line 1681, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Comment: I don't understand why you get the error because you used `str(Mat_ID)` to convert the key to a string, but the error complains it is an integer.

Comment: Me neither! By the end i decided that the total price doesnt need to be affected by the materials ,  neither the price of material should be shown. I just wanted the cost of them and now it's not that compliacated. I will try again the way you show me , i think it was the best solution and easier for me to understand it because of the way you explained me. Thank you anyways!